# Replace text on webpage using script with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, replace, tampermonkey, userscripts

I want to replace spices name in pages like this one: https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?locale=en&place_id=97391&preferred_place_id=8860&taxon_id=61902&view=species

So I want to replace for example 'Chrysolina fastuosa' to something different with this code:

```
var replaceArry = [
    [/Chrysolina fastuosa/gi,    'Złotka jasnotowa'],

    
];
var numTerms    = replaceArry.length;
var txtWalker   = document.createTreeWalker (
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    {   acceptNode: function (node) {
            
            if (node.nodeValue.trim() )
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;

            return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
        }
    },
    false
);
var txtNode     = null;

while (txtNode  = txtWalker.nextNode () ) {
    var oldTxt  = txtNode.nodeValue;

    for (var J  = 0;  J < numTerms;  J++) {
        oldTxt  = oldTxt.replace (replaceArry[J][0], replaceArry[J][1]);
    }
    txtNode.nodeValue = oldTxt;
}
```

But that code don't work on this page. This code works perfectly on headers, plain text, but not where I need it. What I need to change to make it work?

Comment: While your code may or may not contain problems, it's also important that the site loads its content later, so you have to delay the replacement attempt. Either find a suitable event, even inject event handler code somewhere, or you can just resort to a timer. `setTimeout(()=>{for(let beetle of document.getElementsByClassName("sciname"))beetle.childNodes[1].textContent=beetle.childNodes[1].textContent.replace("Chrysolina","Uglybug");},5000);` works for me for example (attempting the replacement after a 5-second delay)

Comment: That works for me. Thanks, I didn't know about timeout.